# concatenating two int in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there an easy way without having to use java library to concat two int? Maybe math?

say I have 9 and 10 , then I want it to be 910, or 224 and 225 then I want it to be 224225.

Comment: Do you want the result to also be an integer?

Comment: am i missing something? how about this: String result=9+""+10; or int i=Integer.valueOf(9+""+10);

Comment: yes! final result as integer please!

Comment: Related for C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700497/how-to-concatenate-two-integers-in-c

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Anything in `java.lang.*` should be fair game...

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(9) + Integer.toString(10));
```

---

Addendum:

I do not like the following the syntax because the operator overloading doesn't declare intent as clearly as the above. Mainly because if the empty string is mistakenly taken out, the result is different.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(9 + "" + 10);
```

Comment: I like to make it this `int a = Integer.parseInt(9 +""+ 10)`. Much more precise.

Comment: @Adeel -- I disagree. Read my comments on pst's answer.

Comment: @Jeremy: That doesn't hold here. Because if you accidentally remove the `empty_quotes`, then next morning you will think why should I parse `int` to `int`. And that should give you a hint that you have never been that stupid to do it in first place. So, there must be something missing. Oh yeah `empty_quotes`.

Comment: I made those comments before the OP requested the final result to be an integer instead of a string. If you really want to get nitty gritty, my answer _is_ more precise. Yours is just syntactic sugar. Either way, it accomplishes the same task.

Comment: @Adeel: I don't see how that can be "more precise". If anything, it is shorter.

Comment: @Grodriguez: okay so, yes it is shorter. @Jeremy: Its perfectly fine what you suggested. I just shared my likeness. And yeah I claimed that that is precise, but may be not, just a little shorter.

Answer (score 18):

This will give you an integer back as expected but only works when `b > 0`.

```
int a = 224;
int b = 225;
int c = (int) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(b))+1)*a + b; // 224225
```

Just a quick explanation:  This determines the number of digits in `b`, then computes a multiplication factor for `a` such that it would move in base 10 by one more digit than `b`.

In this example, `b` has 3 digits, `floor(log10(b))` returns 2 (do this intuitively as `10^2=100`, `10^3 = 1000`, we're somewhere in between at 225).  Then we compute a multiplication factor of `10^(2+1)`, this is `1000`.  When we multiply `a` by 1000 we get `224000`.  Adding `224000` to `225` yields the desired `224225`.

This fails at `b == 0` because `log10(0)` is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

You (likely) want string concatenation (you may also want an integer result, if that is the case, see the other answers). If this is true, about the concatenation, imagine a and b are integers:

```
"" + a + b
```

This works because the + operator is overloaded if either operand is a String. It then converts the other operand to a string (if needed) and results in a new concatenated string. You could also invoke `Integer.toString(a) + Integer.toString(b)` or using an appropriate `String.format` but those methods are more long-winded.

Comment: I've always disliked this notation. If the string was somehow taken out, the intention of concatenating `a` and `b` isn't clear.

Comment: @Jeremy Static typing is my friend :-)

Comment: My point was that if I accidentally took out the string late Friday and came back in Monday morning to fix my code, I would have assumed that they wanted `Integer.toString(a+b)`

Comment: @Jeremy - I see your point, but that is (IMO) a really weak argument.  There are lots of small changes that one can make to a Java program that obscure the original intention; e.g. change `+` to `*` in an arithmetic expression, change `&&` to `||`.  The real answer is to be careful when reading and modifying code.

Comment: @Stephen -- Those are different. Here we are using an overloaded operator where `2+""` and 2+3` have completely different meanings. Sure, there is static analysis which will be enough. I'm not saying *never* do this kind of thing because `System.out.println("Hello there, it is the year "+year)` is a lot clearer. Just to be careful in situations like this.

Comment: @Jeremy - you seem to have misunderstood my comment.  The kind or degree of difference is not relevant to what I'm saying.

Comment: @Stephen - I understand what you're saying and I agree. Being a careful coder is my point as well. If you have a potentially ambiguous statement (whether or not the compile can fine errors), you need to write it better or document it well. There are plenty of people who are careless when coding. I suppose I need to put just as much care into my English then my coding, haha.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my version which works when a,b >= 0.

It is a bit longer, but is 10x faster than the log approach and 5x faster than appending strings.

```
int concat(int a, int b)
{
   if ( b == 0 )
      a *= 10;
   else
   {
      int tempB = b;
      while ( tempB > 0 )
      {
         tempB /= 10;
         a *= 10;
      }
   }
   return a + b;
}
```

Feel free to modify this to work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

a + "" + b

results in error "incompatible types"

```
// The left operand to previousOperator.
private int leftOperand;
```

leftOperand = leftOperand + " " + number;

number is defined as int in the method declaration

This works

import java.lang.*

leftOperand = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(leftOperand) + Integer.toString(number));