# How to concatenate two integers in C

Tags: c, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

Stack Overflow has this question answered in many other languages, but not C.  So I thought I'd ask, since I have the same issue.

**How does one concatenate two integers in C?**

Example:

```
x = 11;
y = 11;
```

I would like z as follows:

```
z = 1111;
```

Other examples attempt to do this with strings.  What is a way to do this without strings?

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this in C because in my particular usage, this is going into a time critical part of code.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Like `100 * x + y`?

Comment: Did you want C or C++?  The answers will be _very_ different from each other.  I'd assume C from the title.

Comment: Needs to be C thanks.

Comment: 100 * x + y fails when y == 0.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
unsigned concatenate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
    return x * pow + y;        
}
```

Proof of [compilation/correctness/speed](http://ideone.com/hbWgE)

I avoid the `log10` and `pow` functions, because I'm pretty sure they use floating point and are slowish, so this *might* be faster on your machine.  Maybe.  Profile.

Comment: I think nothing can beat your answer.

Comment: Must be `y >= pow`, I don't think `concatenate(1,10)` should be 20.

Comment: You are correct sir, for certain numbers mine was inaccurate.  Fixed.

Comment: Also, I totally did not call this being 17 times faster than david's answer, much less 23 times faster than Drummer's.

Comment: I don't get correct results with this. `concatenate(10, 1)` returns 11.

Comment: I chose this one because it worked and because it didn't use the pow or log functions.  In my particular case, the floating point stuff will create too much overhead.  Thanks everyone!!

Comment: @DrummerB: There, I added more correctness tests, and mine passes them all.  Yours and David's fail when `y==0` fyi.

Comment: @010110110101: Don't make that assumption, floating point takes far less overhead than most people think.  MEASURE IT.

Comment: Be nice.  This is going into an embedded microcontroller. The "overhead" I was referring to is the amount of machine code that the floating point stuff generates.

Comment: @Ahmad: Yes it does, I even cover that in the test I linked to.  Lines 80, 81, and 83.

Comment: @MooingDuck nothing, it just looks cleaner.

Comment: There is a potential infinite loop: for example try `concatenate(1, 1000000000)` on 32-bit systems. You could avoid it with `if (pow > UINT_MAX / 10) return y;` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 12):

```
z = x * pow(10, log10(y)+1) + y;
```

**Explanation:**

First you get the number of digits of the variable that should come second:

```
int digits = log10(y)+1;  // will be 2 in your example
```

Then you "shift" the other variable by multiplying it with 10^digits.

```
int shifted = x * pow(10, digits);   // will be 1100 in your example
```

Finally you add the second variable:

```
z = shifted + y;   // 1111
```

Or in one line:

```
z = x * pow(10, (int)log10(y)+1) + y;
```

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer because you actually explained stuff.

Comment: Best to avoid floating point math for an integer problem.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be an optimal or fast solution but no one mentioned it and it's a simple one and could be useful.

You could use `sprintf()` and a `strtol()`.

```
char str[100];
int i=32, j=45;
sprintf(str, "%d%d", i, j);
int result=strtol(str, NULL, 10);
```

You first write to a string the numbers one followed by the another with `sprintf()` (just like you would print to the stdout with `printf()`) and then convert the resultant string to the number with `strtol()`.

`strtol()` returns a `long` which may be a value greater than what can be stored in an `int`, so you may want to check the resultant value first.

```
int result;
long rv=strtol(str, NULL, 10);
if(rv>INT_MAX || rv<INT_MIN || errno==ERANGE)
{
    perror("Something went wrong.");
}
else
{
    result=rv;
}
```

If the value returned by `strtol()` is not within the range of an `int` (ie, not between (including) `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`), error occurred. `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` are from `limits.h`.

If the value of in the string is too big to be represented in a `long`, `errno` will be set to `ERANGE` (from `errno.h`) because of the overflow.

Read about `strtol()` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Edit:

As the enlightening comment by [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) pointed out, negative numbers would cause trouble with this approach.

You could use this or a modification of this to get around that

```
char str[100], temp[50];
int i=-32, j=45, result;
sprintf(temp, "%+d", j);
sprintf(str, "%d%s", i, temp+1);
long rv=strtol(str, NULL, 10);
```

First print the second number to a character array `temp` along with its sign.

The `+` in `%+d` will cause the sign of the number to be printed.

Now print the first number and the second number to `str` but without the sign part of the second number. We skip the sign part of the second number by ignoring the first character in `temp`.

Finally the `strtol()` is done.

Comment: This is a good approach for dealing with potential overflow. Adding the corresponding code, setting and testing `errno` and comparing the result with `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` would be helpful. Negative values of `i` or `j` would also cause problems.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for taking the time to tell us that. I had not thought of the problem of negative numbers. Or the need to look at `INT_MIN`.

Comment: `if(rv>INT_MAX || rv<INT_MIN || errno==ERANGE)` should be `if(rv>LONG_MAX || rv<LONG_MIN || errno==ERANGE)`.  In general, this fails to detect error in `strtol("!!!", ...)` as `errno` is not certainly set.

Answer (score 2):

```
int myPow(int x, int p)
{
     if (p == 0) return 1;
     if (p == 1) return x;

     int tmp = myPow(x, p/2);
     if (p%2 == 0) return tmp * tmp;
     else return x * tmp * tmp;
}
int power = log10(y);
z = x*myPow(10,power+1)+y;
```

Here I shamelessly copied myPow from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1505791/1194873

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation of @Mooing Duck's answer that uses a lookup table for multiples of 10 (for platform's with slow integer multiply)  It also returns unsigned long long to allow for larger values and uses unsigned long long in the lookup table to account for @chqrlie's comment about infinite loops.  If the combined inputs can be guaranteed to not exceed unsigned, those could be changed.

```
static const unsigned long long pow10s[] = {
   10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000,1000000000,10000000000
};
unsigned long long concat(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    const unsigned long long *p = pow10s;
    while (y >= *p) ++p;
    return *p * x +y;        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Macro to concatnate Strings ( Easy way )

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define change(a,b) a##b
int main()
 {
    int y;
    y=change(12,34);
    printf("%d",y);
    return 0;
 }
```

It has one Disadvantage. We can't pass arguments in this method

Answer (score 1):

here's another way to do it:

```
int concat(int x, int y) {
    int temp = y;
    while (y != 0) {
        x *= 10;
        y /= 10;
    }
    return x + temp;
}
```

who knows what performance you'll get. just try and see..

Comment: `concat(123, 0)` returns `123` and not `1230`.  Suggest a `do ... while` loop.

Comment: This really is the best answer, once edge case fixed.  I'd use `unsigned` too, but OP is fuzzy on that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
int x=11,y=11,temp=0;
int z=x;
while(y>0)
{
    // take reciprocal of y into temp
    temp=(temp*10)+(y%10);       
    y=y/10;
}
while(temp>0)
{
    // take each number from last of temp and add to last of z
    z=(z*10)+(temp%10);      
    temp=temp/10;
}
```

code is lengthy , but is simple.
correct me if there is any mistakes.

Comment: http://ideone.com/hbWgE "Assertion `func(0, 10) == 10' failed".   There's probably other edge cases too.

Answer (score 0):

Improved variation on [@Mooing Duck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700533/2410359) and [@none](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12707803/2410359) answers.

Simply decimal shift `x` as needed.

```
unsigned concatenate2(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  unsigned y_temp = y;
  do {  // do loop to insure at least one shift
    x *= 10;
    y_temp /= 10;
  } while (y_temp > 0);
  return x + y;  
}
```

Could use wider math to reduce overflow possibilites. [@technosaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46576166/2410359)

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uintmax_t concatenate2(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  uintmax_t x_temp = x;
  unsigned y_temp = y;
  do {  // do loop to insure at least one shift
    x_temp *= 10;
    y_temp /= 10;
  } while (y_temp > 0);
  return x_temp + y;  
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0,count=0,c=0,t=0;
    cout<<"enter 2 no"<<endl;
    cin>>a>>b;
    t=b;

    while(b!=0)
    {
        b=b/10;
        count++;
    }

    while(count!=0)
    {
        a=a*10;
        count--;
        c=a+t;
    }

    cout<<"concate no is:"<<c;
}
```

Comment: The OP seeks for a solution in C. You provided a solution in C++, because you are using `cin` and `cout`. Moreover, you answer an old question which has already several well received answers. Why is your solution better so that it is worth posting?