# Decimal concatenation of two integers using bit operations

Tags: c, algorithm, concatenation, bit-manipulation, micro-optimization

I want to concatenate two integers using only bit operations since  i need efficiency as much as possible.There are various answers available but they are not fast enough what I want is implementation that uses only bit operations like left shift,or and etc.
Please guide me how to do it.

example

```
int x=32;
int y=12;
int result=3212;
```

I am having and FPGA implentation of AES.I need this on my system to reduce time consumption of some task

Comment: try here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700497/how-to-concatenate-two-integers-in-c

Comment: `but they are not fast enough` So how much speed you want and how you major speed and which solutions you try?

Comment: That you can't do with bitwise operations. You can do it with normal multiplication and addition.

Comment: I have checked that link it did not contain what I need.

Comment: I am having and FPGA implentation of AES.I need this on my system to reduce time consumption of some task.

Comment: @khan what makes you think binary operations are the best option here? Just because you've heard binary operations can speed up some operations does not mean they are the best option *everywhere*

Comment: From your description, it sounds as if you want to concatenate the decimal numbers 32 and 12. Note that you need to consider that 3212 is not the concatenation of the bits that 32 and 12 make. 12 is 0x0C, 32 is 0x10 but 0x100c is 4108 while 3212 is 0x0C8C. Just or'ing the binary bits (after a shift) is not sufficient.

Comment: @sabbahillel I knew it that is why I did not do it like that.

Comment: @lyayloStrandjev I am FPGA programmer and most of the time I do bit wise operations on my code on client side in C and that works 70% of the time

Comment: The answer depends a lot on how variable you need this to be. Should it work for any combination of decimal numbers or only for 2 digit ones? Do you need to handle signed numbers (and if not, why are you using int)?

Comment: @Lundin I posted it as int for example in my implementation I am using unsigned.

Comment: How are you going to define if int '12' should be treated as '12' or '012' or '0012'...?

Comment: Must we use bitwise operations? Or can we just give you a faster way to achieve that?

Comment: @black Faster will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most efficient way to do it, is likely something similar to this:

```
uint32_t uintcat (uint32_t ms, uint32_t ls)
{
  uint32_t mult=1;

  do
  {
    mult *= 10; 
  } while(mult <= ls);

  return ms * mult + ls;
}
```

Then let the compiler worry about optimization. There's likely not a lot it can improve since this is base 10, which doesn't get along well with the various instructions of the computer, like shifting.

---

**EDIT : BENCHMARK TEST**

```
Intel i7-3770 2 3,4 GHz
OS: Windows 7/64
Mingw, GCC version 4.6.2
gcc -O3 -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall

10 million random values, from 0 to 3276732767.
```

Result (approximates):

```
Algorithm 1: 60287 micro seconds
Algorithm 2: 65185 micro seconds
```

Benchmark code used:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

uint32_t uintcat (uint32_t ms, uint32_t ls)
{
  uint32_t mult=1;

  do
  {
    mult *= 10; 
  } while(mult <= ls);

  return ms * mult + ls;
}


uint32_t myConcat (uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    switch( (b >= 10000000) ? 7 : 
            (b >= 1000000) ? 6 : 
            (b >= 100000) ? 5 : 
            (b >= 10000) ? 4 : 
            (b >= 1000) ? 3 : 
            (b >= 100) ? 2 : 
            (b >= 10) ? 1 : 0 ) {
        case 1: return a*100+b; break;
        case 2: return a*1000+b; break;
        case 3: return a*10000+b; break;
        case 4: return a*100000+b; break;
        case 5: return a*1000000+b; break;
        case 6: return a*10000000+b; break;
        case 7: return a*100000000+b; break;

        default: return a*10+b; break;
    }
}


static LARGE_INTEGER freq;

static void print_benchmark_results (LARGE_INTEGER* start, LARGE_INTEGER* end)
{
  LARGE_INTEGER elapsed;

  elapsed.QuadPart = end->QuadPart - start->QuadPart;
  elapsed.QuadPart *= 1000000;
  elapsed.QuadPart /= freq.QuadPart;

  printf("%lu micro seconds", elapsed.QuadPart);
}

int main()
{
  const uint32_t TEST_N = 10000000;
  uint32_t* data1 = malloc (sizeof(uint32_t) * TEST_N);
  uint32_t* data2 = malloc (sizeof(uint32_t) * TEST_N);
  volatile uint32_t* result_algo1 = malloc (sizeof(uint32_t) * TEST_N);
  volatile uint32_t* result_algo2 = malloc (sizeof(uint32_t) * TEST_N);

  srand (time(NULL));
  // Mingw rand() apparently gives numbers up to 32767
  // worst case should therefore be 3,276,732,767

  // fill up random data in arrays
  for(uint32_t i=0; i<TEST_N; i++)
  {
    data1[i] = rand();
    data2[i] = rand();
  }


  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq); 


  LARGE_INTEGER start, end;

  // run algorithm 1
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
  for(uint32_t i=0; i<TEST_N; i++)
  {
    result_algo1[i] = uintcat(data1[i], data2[i]);
  } 
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

  // print results
  printf("Algorithm 1: ");
  print_benchmark_results(&start, &end);
  printf("\n");

  // run algorithm 2
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);
  for(uint32_t i=0; i<TEST_N; i++)
  {
    result_algo2[i] = myConcat(data1[i], data2[i]);
  } 
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

  // print results
  printf("Algorithm 2: ");
  print_benchmark_results(&start, &end);
  printf("\n\n");


  // sanity check both algorithms against each other
  for(uint32_t i=0; i<TEST_N; i++)
  {
    if(result_algo1[i] != result_algo2[i])
    {
      printf("Results mismatch for %lu %lu. Expected: %lu%lu, algo1: %lu, algo2: %lu\n",
             data1[i], 
             data2[i],
             data1[i],
             data2[i],
             result_algo1[i],
             result_algo2[i]);
    }
  }


  // clean up
  free((void*)data1);
  free((void*)data2);
  free((void*)result_algo1);
  free((void*)result_algo2);
}
```

Comment: Avoid division and save one variable: `for( mul=1; mul<=ls; mul*=10);`.

Comment: @CiaPan That is indeed a much better idea, I will edit and update.

Comment: The for loop has a bug when ls has value 0 though. I'll update to fix.

Comment: NOTE: data has to be declared as volatile or GCC -O3 is too smart for its own good. It somehow seemed to re-use the results from the first algorithm, so I got the same results for both. When I swapped the order of execution of the algorithms, then algo 2 suddenly performed worse. volatile seems to have solved this optimization hiccup.

Comment: Further optimization: Use binary search in `myConcat` to come up with the key for `switch()`.

Comment: Well, I've tried to benchmark this fairly, but benchmarking _anything_ in Windows' "realtime" is really quite questionable practice... And then there's GCC. If I prevent it from using function inlining, algo 1 suddenly drops heavily in performance.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I'm not sure that would increase performance. That algorithm as it is performs quicker on larger numbers and slower on smaller numbers. Assuming completely random data, then there's roughly an average of 3.5 branches per call. Binary search would give a more deterministic average of something like 3 branches per call, but it would perform poorly at the larger numbers. Looking back, my test was actually in favour of that method, because it wasn't completely random, but most likely had numbers above 10 mil. Gonna try the test again with a restriction of 10 mil...

Comment: Conclusions: algorithm 1 seems slightly more effective for this particular test, although if I prevent function inlining by passing it as a function pointer to another function, it takes a severe performance hit and then gets slower than algo 2. Algorithm 2 performs ok when larger numbers are expected, but not too surprisingly, it gets much slower if the input is restricted to small numbers only. With `rand() % 10` as data seed, algo 2 performs really bad in comparison with algo 1.

Comment: Also, algo 1 seems to actually perform better with -O1 than -O3.

Comment: @Lundin Start with multiplier=10, `mult=10; while(mult<=ls) mult*=10;`. This saves one loop iteration (comparision and multiplication) and guarantees ls=0 being properly represented in the result.

Comment: @Lundin: Actually, you're right but your explanation is wrong :-) http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog10Obvious

Comment: @AaronDigulla Probably... I don't care much about the theory, because the usual problem with all computer science theory is that it's obsessed with the number of comparisons, as if that's the hardest thing a computer could ever do. Maybe it was so in 1960. Branching, stacking parameters as well as the actual calculations is what takes time. So imo algorithm theory is pretty useless, try the code in the real world instead.

Comment: What if ls=04 and ms=32, shouldnt the output be 3204 actually vs 324 ?

Comment: If used repeatedly in a loop, a lookup table based on `clz(ls)` for an initial `mult` value could be a win.

Answer (score 5):

Bit operations use the binary representation of the numbers. However what you try to achieve is to concatenate the numbers in decimal notation. Please note that concatenating the decimal representations has little to do with concatenating the binary representations. Though it is theoretically possible to solve the problem using binary operations I am sure it will be far from the most efficient way.

Comment: @A-B-BI think I am missing your point. Why do you think decimal is inefficient for this problem? What binary approach are you comparing to?

Comment: @A-B-B it is not efficient to use binary representation to solve this particular task since we want to concatenate the *decimal* representation of two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We need to calculate a*10^N + b very fast.

Bit operations isn't a best idea to optimize it (even using tricks like a := (a<<1) + (a<<3) <=> a := a*10 as compiler can make it himself).

The first problem is to calculate 10^N, but there is no need to calculate it, there is just 9 possible values.

The second problem is to calculate N from b (length of 10 representation). If your data have uniform distribution you can minimize operations count in average case.

Check b <= 10^9, b <= 10^8, ..., b <= 10 with ()?: (it's faster than if( ) after optimizations, it has much simplier grammar and functionality), call the result N. Next, make switch(N) with lines "return a*10^N + b" (where 10^N is constant). As I know, switch() with 3-4 "case" is faster than same if( ) construction after optimizations.

```
unsigned int myConcat(unsigned int& a, unsigned int& b) {
    switch( (b >= 10000000) ? 7 : 
            (b >= 1000000) ? 6 : 
            (b >= 100000) ? 5 : 
            (b >= 10000) ? 4 : 
            (b >= 1000) ? 3 : 
            (b >= 100) ? 2 : 
            (b >= 10) ? 1 : 0 ) {
        case 1: return a*100+b; break;
        case 2: return a*1000+b; break;
        case 3: return a*10000+b; break;
        case 4: return a*100000+b; break;
        case 5: return a*1000000+b; break;
        case 6: return a*10000000+b; break;
        case 7: return a*100000000+b; break;
        default: return a*10+b; break;
        // I don't really know what to do here
        //case 8: return a*1000*1000*1000+b; break;
        //case 9: return a*10*1000*1000*1000+b; break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is 2-3 operations in average case + optimisations is very effective here. I've benchmarked it in comparison with Lundin's suggestion, [here is the result](http://ideone.com/Cl5oix). 0ms vs 100ms

Comment: This will be quite ineffective on a CPU that uses branch prediction. Also, the question is tagged C.

Comment: I am really interested why is it so? Here is almost same C code http://ideone.com/XiSKxR , there is no difference in perfomance. But still, I've read wiki "branch prediction", there is so many prediction methods, and I have no idea why multiplications by 10 is faster than optimized conditional sentences?

Comment: I'm no Intel CPU guru so I can't give you a detailed explanation. Simply put, modern CPUs do predictable calculations extremely fast, while branching is less ideal. Your benchmarking seems way off, I will write some benchmarking of my own and update.

Comment: I've learned some from your code, and I'm interested how can I do the same under linux. But tests wasn't fair) Chosen input data (0..RAND_MAX) makes algo2 doing useless operations every call. Take away 5,6,7 cases and it will be faster (1:91109, 2:63667, same compiler and parameters). It's a question of expected data what is better, so I think the best solution will be merge those codes) switch for big numbers, while for small. Anyway, I've also learned how real answer should looks, thanks)

Comment: I'm still not certain which algorithm that is fastest. To design an optimal test for this and to benchmark it properly is really quite hard. And as usual, it really doesn't make any sense to manually optimize code without a specific target in mind. In the end, I think both algorithms are "fast enough" for some vague FPGA algorithm specification. With a more narrow spec, it would be possible to make much faster code.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about decimal digit concatenation, you might want to simply do that as you're printing, and convert both numbers to a sequence of digits sequentially.  e.g. [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166064/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-assembly-level-programming-without-printf-from-the/46301894#46301894) shows an efficient C function, as well as asm.  Call it twice into the same buffer.

---

@Lundin's answer loops increasing powers of 10 to find 
the right decimal-shift, i.e. a linear search for the right power of 10.  If it's called very frequently so a lookup table can stay hot in cache, a speedup maybe be possible.

**If you can use [GNU C `__builtin_clz`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) (Count Leading Zeros) or some other way of quickly finding the MSB position of the right-hand input (`ls`, the least-significant part of the resulting concatenation), you can start the search for the right `mult` from a 32-entry lookup table.**  (And you only have to check at most one more iteration, so it's not a loop.)

Most of the common modern CPU architectures have a HW instruction that the compiler can use directly or with a bit of processing to implement clz.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support.  (And on all but x86, the result is well-defined for an input of 0, but unfortunately GNU C doesn't portably give us access to that.)

***If* the table stays hot in L1d cache, this can be pretty good**.  The extra latency of a `clz` and a table lookup are comparable to a couple iterations of the loop (on a modern x86 like Skylake or Ryzen for example, where `bsf` or `tzcnt` is 3 cycle latency, L1d latency is 4 or 5 cycles, `imul` latency is 3 cycles.)

Of course, on many architectures (including x86), multiplying by 10 is cheaper than by a runtime variable, using shift and add.  2 LEA instructions on x86, or an `add`+`lsl` on ARM/AArch64 using a shifted input to do `tmp = x + x*4` with the add.  So on Intel CPUs, we're only looking at a 2-cycle loop-carried dependency chain, not 3.  But AMD CPUs have slower LEA when using a scaled index.

This doesn't sound great for small numbers.  But **it can reduce branch mispredictions by needing at most one iteration.  It even makes a branchless implementation possible**.  And it means less total work for large lower parts (large powers of 10).  But large integers will easily overflow unless you use a wider result type.

---

Unfortunately, 10 is not a power of 2, so the MSB position alone can't give us the exact power of 10 to multiply by.  e.g. all numbers from 64 to 127 all have MSB = `1<<7`, but some of them have 2 decimal digits and some have 3.  Since we want to avoid division (because it requires a multiplication by a magic constant and shifting the high half), we want to always start with the lower power of 10 and see if that's big enough.

**But fortunately, a bitscan does get us within one power of 10 so we no longer need a loop.**

I probably wouldn't have written the part with `_lzcnt_u32` or ARM `__clz` if I'd learned of the `clz(a|1)` trick for avoiding problems with input=0 beforehand.  But I did, and played around with the source a bit to try to get nicer asm from gcc and clang.  Index the table on clz or BSR depending on target platform makes it a bit of a mess.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>

   // builtin_clz matches Intel's docs for x86 BSR: garbage result for input=0
   // actual x86 HW leaves the destination register unmodified; AMD even documents this.
   // but GNU C doesn't let us take advantage with intrinsics.
   // unless you use BMI1 _lzcnt_u32


// if available, use an intrinsic that gives us a leading-zero count
// *without* an undefined result for input=0
#ifdef __LZCNT__      // x86 CPU feature
#include <immintrin.h>  // Intel's intrinsics
#define HAVE_LZCNT32
#define lzcnt32(a) _lzcnt_u32(a)
#endif

#ifdef __ARM__      // TODO: do older ARMs not have this?
#define HAVE_LZCNT32
#define lzcnt32(a) __clz(a)  // builtin, no header needed
#endif

// Some POWER compilers define `__cntlzw`?



// index = msb position, or lzcnt, depending on which the HW can do more efficiently
// defined later; one or the other is unused and optimized out, depending on target platform
// alternative: fill this at run-time startup
// with a loop that does mult*=10 when (x<<1)-1 > mult, or something
//#if INDEX_BY_MSB_POS == 1
  __attribute__((unused))
  static const uint32_t catpower_msb[] = {
       10,    // 1 and 0
       10,    // 2..3
       10,    // 4..7
       10,    // 8..15
       100,    // 16..31     // 2 digits even for the low end of the range
       100,    // 32..63
       100,    // 64..127
       1000,   // 128..255   // 3 digits
       1000,   // 256..511
       1000,   // 512..1023
       10000,   // 1024..2047
       10000,   // 2048..4095
       10000,   // 4096..8191
       10000,   // 8192..16383
       100000,   // 16384..32767
       100000,   // 32768..65535      // up to 2^16-1, enough for 16-bit inputs
       //  ...   // fill in the rest yourself
  };
//#elif INDEX_BY_MSB_POS == 0
  // index on leading zeros
  __attribute__((unused))
  static const uint32_t catpower_lz32[] = {
      // top entries overflow: 10^10 doesn't fit in uint32_t
      // intentionally wrong to make it easier to spot bad output.
    4000000000,    // 2^31 .. 2^32-1    2*10^9 .. 4*10^9
    2000000000,    // 1,073,741,824 .. 2,147,483,647
    // first correct entry
    1000000000,    //   536,870,912 .. 1,073,741,823

    // ... fill in the rest
    // for testing, skip until 16 leading zeros
    [16] = 100000,   // 32768..65535      // up to 2^16-1, enough for 16-bit inputs
       100000,   // 16384..32767
       10000,   // 8192..16383
       10000,   // 4096..8191
       10000,   // 2048..4095
       10000,   // 1024..2047
       1000,   // 512..1023
       1000,   // 256..511
       1000,   // 128..255
       100,    // 64..127
       100,    // 32..63
       100,    // 16..31     // low end of the range has 2 digits
       10,    // 8..15
       10,    // 4..7
       10,    // 2..3
       10,    // 1
                       // lzcnt32(0) == 32
       10,    // 0     // treat 0 as having one significant digit.
  };
//#else
//#error "INDEX_BY_MSB_POS not set correctly"
//#endif



//#undef HAVE_LZCNT32  // codegen for the other path, for fun

static inline uint32_t msb_power10(uint32_t a)
{
#ifdef HAVE_LZCNT32  // 0-safe lzcnt32 macro available
    #define INDEX_BY_MSB_POS 0
    // a |= 1 would let us shorten the table, in case 32*4 is a lot nicer than 33*4 bytes
    unsigned lzcnt = lzcnt32(a);  // 32 for a=0
    return catpower_lz32[lzcnt];
#else
  // only generic __builtin_clz available

  static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(unsigned) && UINT_MAX == (1ULL<<32)-1, "__builtin_clz isn't 32-bit");
  // See also https://foonathan.net/blog/2016/02/11/implementation-challenge-2.html
  // for C++ templates for fixed-width wrappers for __builtin_clz

  #if defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__)
    // x86 where MSB_index = 31-clz = BSR is most efficient
    #define INDEX_BY_MSB_POS 1
    unsigned msb = 31 - __builtin_clz(a|1);  // BSR
    return catpower_msb[msb];
    //return unlikely(a==0) ? 10 : catpower_msb[msb];
  #else
    // use clz directly while still avoiding input=0
    // I think all non-x86 CPUs with hardware CLZ do define clz(0) = 32 or 64 (the operand width),
    // but gcc's builtin is still documented as not valid for input=0
    // Most ISAs like PowerPC and ARM that have a bitscan instruction have clz, not MSB-index

    // set the LSB to avoid the a==0 special case
    unsigned clz = __builtin_clz(a|1);
    // table[32] unused, could add yet another #ifdef for that
    #define INDEX_BY_MSB_POS 0
    //return unlikely(a==0) ? 10 : catpower_lz32[clz];
    return catpower_lz32[clz];   // a|1 avoids the special-casing
  #endif  // optimize for BSR or not
#endif // HAVE_LZCNT32
}


uint32_t uintcat (uint32_t ms, uint32_t ls)
{
//  if (ls==0) return ms * 10;  // Another way to avoid the special case for clz

  uint32_t mult = msb_power10(ls); // catpower[clz(ls)];
  uint32_t high = mult * ms;
#if 0
  if (mult <= ls)
      high *= 10;
  return high + ls;
#else
  // hopefully compute both and then select
  // because some CPUs can shift and add at the same time (x86, ARM)
  // so this avoids having an ADD *after* the cmov / csel, if the compiler is smart
  uint32_t another10 = high*10 + ls;
  uint32_t enough = high + ls; 
  return (mult<=ls) ? another10 : enough;
#endif
}
```

**[From the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8tZK1NYA1FtsBhIwXz1uCB7YWhIAgnYOTi6Y7l6seAC2hEYBQSHhvPaOzm4ensxGRpjEBKm2wWHpdlhUDjGmtPEA1pisAJ4QmAAeAA7EAJSuAPpDAEameKwEDkPdPZjIBBBgK5BzA6SuEv1VmTV1rs2tHeuDI%2BOT07SzvQtLq2u9G66cO5Vhrp8A9F%2BuF1MzJwAL1cCWYBGQCEwRlcAEl6K0wFYYehUMgYTRiK4uvwAGyuXQMABKIFcwGYxFGzGAMWI0NMU1cmNcDh6pgIHgAIhJ0p9XD9XMxFqY2Ni8a4ABIAdUOmGYADdoa4CFDXFgfA5wXg6K46cA8D5iq4GgkMHhaph0B5dK5QgBZTmuTCK2hqtGmBKYegwlUG7i876/cYEVwAcQAcgBVVyeN3Q2hIkPsEOmH3MFqC9Dy9QEakxADuhAQLPoxAcRjw6P9H0Dxsa0JhbTMxqKBLtsM4w1YQOQ9CGplsvCq71CAvNguzk2Yo3Ym1TMXUJYIZdoFeQyoQ4LJeEVMNTgtlzD8wAAtEDiqhXGgGhywgKAFSFlVmAj3wWuhr7WiW3X0xnM1l2S5HlKkyc0amGIYABkAC1PHDAAVEY%2BT5AUcXxTwAAVoyoOUCHMTBdiyKJci8RIklLBwymwWt4QIRFkSXFc1yMIivxiCVQgANWwaC4MQwc2MwWpv0OHt6EHCBmDObtewIftJOkoivXwKhhwyewqAgkZQiJO1kJQ/lfgQgB5TkTNJVFXFQVgsCxXS7RhWhUBDTdFQ3A0PAAMSEkSOO43jYPghDBNA2x2LEuTFLOIZgSkwYjL%2BCYAVoTZnNcKEjyNb9LUtZTaFU9SBQYVBPVcTCTKlbAiSvUqekmYoUWEg4tFxCQRjk7t81anlbB8kcxwK7pYkdBIjFGVwelQCtpjoTYSEi%2BhNiweYCocYBrNdfMEErYsVQ4mUWFdKzTTpJ0qFqZA8C9Ah2nSAV2PQQ5wWKa1NpiBb9us/asQNOt5ye9QntQHppiSc9gfZZbMFW49NuVCkaRDHo1AITEEnSHwtXXNBVxTBwCEHIYQxYAgpvzYohjG0YtDEfQxE5a1MdzaYcboHxjQJomSfBcnKe7QS6dpxnbH0Eciq%2BOxP2EyUAr44LB1rNAsBpV1mS%2BlyoSxHpwQQTZmSoBp1Kx1mS3iUSJgk3hidBcahj54hOAkCBLcJ62QyUyppDFjTwJlziePlgTeFrCQTyMZhcMWt3QSFYhLwVZgpxnQia0%2BapmtE2Fw05bAAA0hl0ABNIY7QYXQhgqhgtgDWtmHcaRPC5F5XHzMxbNlFMYSMBASHo10vtzFPNgcK8ChiQd7xEFkYXr1gXNcWhKyNFVF1sWwp7%2BNp6NYtO6wrYBvye2T6BG6PorexLFeZZhgNr398OIV1SYdoYBaHOmT45BmmbC1oigDAKOg7QyRemKJWSC/wrixW7BOJOagU4BgDCbSsQwChFBKBACs55UBUBdlzd2gwuTN2wZgXBLtVx4EPpaIhvBcQ6HxJGbOSE7ShDziNZuEBOCRiglBPIeRBz9BPJwTYOhrZjGStA4EM8ExWBDIOE8oxCBiJ2KLQBvwGCYAXKwEwGUCBkyMCAH4NA6C63UNwb8BAvgzlQMAL4vAJCcFxF8CQvAvicE4F8RIKNMCenoFqOgJ5IRsHYBoTAJ5eABAIAkVg6imQLSbnoAwypfEoxehiBatQuiWhPIWdAKpW7EGYD0eYxAMlYnOJIwE3Z1LpzAlQNUmdLQQBGHgWweIRhEMbloRujS/LoBaUMdCQxcQiE6ffNC4ptrFBiGXCuDgsBdDPrYTgQTYHN0JDVP6poObCUutdeg98M5%2BThDnfOhcS5zMriZaunB74NAPkfW2E1m4rNcCeSBVTrhxVvo3V4l8BSbPvnSR%2Bz9eaoApsQKm41aa6GpsLX%2BoQUI/BBeYD8jQ8AtHaFJYhthuREL6i8CQrhSQvwhZTeFdNKUix9nU2w/9U5ItQr8ecV5YH4DpIsEB20GquA1KwVgE5UB4DhoBDkeKQJMtoh5WgTRBQCsXoE9CMZsIwifMWTcxB0D5gpDETwsE3R9IOHFbYyyQ4LVGa4CAGtSlA1biKlU/RSATKDOyMkyBkBIhhFA0ef1%2BWCtRMgD0N0fwFEVSGbM8QnoAVoGycV3IXWuDtNNEMsIGChBhEccq5LiCYVjHahyG4txuQXH8ZIR0Sw%2BGIKYRY2pXQlrZUCNKC85kngWd0WpzK%2BWYBDF9KC5dlQJ3lMKp6X1b54uAny%2BYV1RQsAAXvB5VCnnSObpUy41SgQ4r%2Bao2lXah7sFhYLR0DQAabGvB3I8T02g9vfJrI0EQtIy3VpuW8Ur3B7Caac3OBdi6l3Ltc6ukrkVfFRU/OsRxsXjpFvi2IXkiUkrHmTHNb8gSC10MCBFai96gbBUhyFKG0MYZ/qLLtvzPCdgVCOn0qojDTrwGwIJBR1pIMyCpcciUQZgzwOeeJWJNnWSxM5V9dg2MNIFAHQK/EQpDi9ozcWd5fhsHok/LUipSS1AVb6WeIZq20BPGDGIWMSimB6PdX46qDzzxBkWkMqIlQJAZK%2BLkTtW5QldBALo/CvCvGEbEGiDmpjzSxCYT0voNASwfV%2B85v6rlVw4Xil4AYRjgmXHgYMmARhQBPUUdA/Q3hMpQWzPGnMrY2zJfhyl9NHTNx6buwyTtNhdoowVGue8%2BQNeA64SJ3BbD33axIRrtYRDcG4NIPrnwOtdv4CNzgYhxtEoG51pxI23mdZDvgfUBAYTOi9LxjcMR575idC13B%2B3dTqBpPNp2i2u2DhG7iXrbWJsSBu7WUZM3eBjaewt17ApOACBG7wMQYhbtqiockK7L3fu/CB7iEbYgPGQ5e4NgUCPutO0yEj5HTXXHDb4BIEQX2339ahyjmHBPpvcBEBIQQc3vvXex0NmncPuD8E4IIO59OofQ9cGzwQ6OHv8Ee8T573OycvEF3jwc0hcRE8MqL0nt3Pu4kp7iYHtgQeGQFCZwdXXabYCccIzYXozDAGLMyQ3SiQxit3iLxKrgRvcC7RpwVo8vp0g5k2cwRRWBqRrD0mlZmRPxAadnb9Fy/0Vzi7ix0QHErtqWTqdgR51quHPPHW3nxkv6LLOlzLFCAZ5eQSzCBuMOau25oh1%2B79YXCzPrV8bAoiA9GO6lpUqBFTECoId0kTt9cubs0YWRIZajW4/AQ4mjffgExunWkJbRCl0A2kQWOGZCBOiYyvS8tGF5UkhmTdk1Y33U%2B52Ltb%2Bu3kjb12IbACjOx8l4PePvN/BAO6dyIJ/PIX/3wcafxXTXSAJBpBbBSBpARARF%2BBeBp4r9eBSBOBCdSARAhdSBRk5dnc8AykSYSBOUQwbpiA2h74Gc/9Bt7dXAxBbBcRSAZABsOcQ4r8REgCQCwCIDMcRxOtHcmRJhXcB5VQPdX1Ot1ZoQrhgBNgjAmg8AW8bxJgJdDw4Z09pojk6YnE69m4iCedpcVd7t1dNdOsdcV8P4DdcQjdjtTdzcFpLd18bcsdGdEonF2kpdlc0D6sz9aw%2BcBd2lhd5cfsedqdBAWc%2BdOc7ciDxcHEkCRtfC6cgiXDbDcdAcCcnCUIGdxc0cZtXFPD5ckiu1Yd4dEcucbC/sAc%2BBgckcSCBR3tuB/sEiSdSjfg7tuAHsSilsWdVsu1DtjtgYGl3cLsYhNwYR1twcttIcajecZtIivDJshsRsqjnthjut0jnDhjAivDljliBQv5JJTUY9XBQoojhjiVOtlw8IthBQYQ3JU86BDMl1zRKwcwwdNsj905pBA8FNg951RxJZWNiB44sQxEw9otLl/04shNu0sCvi7g7peAZN3iRM1o/dwgRwK93YSsIQtx8FSsQwxo5wJ8kwjB8sG8FNPhxwIAdEY9TUcNbZXA3w%2B8SNEpQghMtZW5mAF8V9KMRUztaMFh6NBU50YhmQMM2DkTK8AsQxm5qZ7Yc0nZiTcS3oBRytXo6Y4odEdhiNd1ESbYdozcz5hTKTbZEVIs48iTtSvNHQlTxsNTix7xVDepd1yTzT30bQSSsMNIGU4le55hDYBUF80AEg40YhRhNZ3xR03Nu12BFg4lRgFhmBWUQs9VVUx5XQe5zQPYWtL1BRe0aNmAyoDMrV0JNgHJ8taxdEtMhURVTiFRU9FxQhORHR7xI5lM3wvpkBTR5R%2BQrwfcR5OjVRvT6p2Bfpu4wQSgAw1Tky71HZiVm5zTP97TDhWInTPhhyTDTBNSJyqFixklHSbQAxySIBhTjSlTYNb0foXNSQTclzAgnSYTCpZMrAnVWAQArAxArBSBaB7yJAnzUB7zEl9A9A%2BUzALAYg7BOAnyCBXybynUmgQAAdrtBBbBwCJA1c6FcQRE7yrARAnyXyrA3zSAPyrAnzDEBsQLMKbzSA4BYAkBuyGoyAKAIAKLeyQBgBIDSANNlNDEIBRhQLSAlFaAKQ2h7ygLSBvS/ECATJGheKiLSAsAwQNB2AOKOU7gdxoQOLugFh2RrB%2BKZ8UKsL4hRgil8DPAMA1LgKywEg%2BLiKaB6AmA2AOAeABBhBxApBZB5AFA1ANAUADADBVA0tDFIAnVOM61DErATwuh1wTwpQQl3kpRuhlx64TwTJbB3kfArQ8VD5TAPF3kBzIQuQxC2g1AMwTwYlxICA8K/zLAuBbz7zHznyOKcL0ITxLVgAPURiQ4IBcBCAFpALNh9KfTKL30VlBgvyDBgLQK8tSAILMhWd7C8QwD2lRlOBpBpBVB7y0KqrxKcK8KQACLhqSKYBEAUA6pKLyBKBaLigUAXLgBpBkdmLGpKB2LxKuKeLTKBLSohKRL2hZLfELsZLxK5La1dwlLskg16JHqNKOLtLdK2h9KsBHrUsTKrAgKnVzLGAWAZKbKhBRBJAZAnLnKLs3Kkk9BPLRhvKIBfLQZ/L7ygqQqwqFVQqoqil3k4qErfAuQUq0r8qKRMq8VsrcqYh8rnITwv5irzBSrXhFqHz0Lqr7zarLUnALtXBpBuAJAFarVWqiAfjMgREYx9rezereB%2Br3K9AhqiKRqxrbAKjZdJBHF/tYKhA8RRblqMKsK1rjANrSBCK3ynVSLdrjqqKjqtaTqSlkBRlQyzqmLLhrq2KOL7r8DHrBKbpXqxKsLJLPrrBE6MD5K/rxLlLAbDLyAERNKnywaeLIac6YbTKEa6AkarKuA%2BA0b7LMasbVAcbtA8bDBtKiaSbZpVxybgqIrwqaauhor6bbBBb/yyrRbKqHb3z7yHYg6YgZaNArVlwGgmhBgWr8BVbeqNauqez71MhbA9aW7Db3bwLILhshBbAgDBAJBbBpA6Fcc7bxbVr7z1rNqjbyqrBeBH7Hbn7XbhqnVO8Kw6AQARAgA%3D)**, this compiles efficiently for x86-64 with and without BSR:

```
# clang7.0 -O3 for x86-64 SysV,  -march=skylake -mno-lzcnt
uintcat(unsigned int, unsigned int):
    mov     eax, esi
    or      eax, 1
    bsr     eax, eax                    # 31-clz(ls|1)
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + catpower_msb]
    imul    edi, ecx                    # high = mult * ms
    lea     eax, [rdi + rdi]
    lea     eax, [rax + 4*rax]          # retval = high * 10
    cmp     ecx, esi
    cmova   eax, edi                    # if(mult>ls) retval = high   (drop the *10 result)
    add     eax, esi                    # retval += ls
    ret
```

Or *with* lzcnt, (enabled by `-march=haswell` or later, or some AMD uarches),

```
uintcat(unsigned int, unsigned int):
          # clang doesn't try to break the false dependency on EAX; gcc uses xor eax,eax
    lzcnt   eax, esi                    # C source avoids the |1, saving instructions
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [4*rax + catpower_lz32]
    imul    edi, ecx                    # same as above from here on
    lea     eax, [rdi + rdi]
    lea     eax, [rax + 4*rax]
    cmp     ecx, esi
    cmova   eax, edi
    add     eax, esi
    ret
```

Factoring the last `add` out of both sides of the ternary is a missed optimization, adding 1 cycle of latency after the `cmov`.  We can multiply by 10 and add just as cheaply as multiplying by 10 alone, on Intel CPUs:

```
    ... same start         # hand-optimized version that clang should use
    imul    edi, ecx                    # high = mult * ms
    lea     eax, [rdi + 4*rdi]          # high * 5
    lea     eax, [rsi + rdi*2]          # retval = high * 10 + ls
    add     edi, esi                    # tmp = high + ls
    cmp     ecx, esi
    cmova   eax, edi                    # if(mult>ls) retval = high+ls
    ret
```

So the `high + ls` latency would run in parallel with the `high*10 + ls` latency, both needed as inputs for `cmov`.

GCC branches instead of using CMOV for the last condition.  GCC also makes a mess of `31-clz(a|1)`, calculating `clz` with `BSR` and `XOR` with 31.  But then subtracting that from 31.  And it has some extra `mov` instructions.  Strangely, gcc seems to do better with that BSR code when `lzcnt` is available, even though it chooses not to use it.

clang has no trouble optimizing away the `31-clz` double-inversion and just using BSR directly.

For PowerPC64, clang also makes branchless asm.  gcc does something similar, but with a branch like on x86-64.

```
uintcat:
.Lfunc_gep0:
    addis 2, 12, .TOC.-.Lfunc_gep0@ha
    addi 2, 2, .TOC.-.Lfunc_gep0@l
    ori 6, 4, 1                              # OR immediate
    addis 5, 2, catpower_lz32@toc@ha
    cntlzw 6, 6                              # CLZ  word
    addi 5, 5, catpower_lz32@toc@l           # static table address
    rldic 6, 6, 2, 30                        # rotate left and clear immediate (shift and zero-extend the CLZ result)
    lwzx 5, 5, 6                             # Load Word Zero eXtend, catpower_lz32[clz]
    mullw 3, 5, 3                            # mul word
    cmplw   5, 4                             # compare   mult, ls
    mulli 6, 3, 10                           # mul immediate
    isel 3, 3, 6, 1                          # conditional select high vs. high*10
    add 3, 3, 4                              # + ls
    clrldi  3, 3, 32                         # zero extend, clearing upper 32 bits
    blr                                      # return
```

---

## Compressing the table

Using `clz(ls|1) >> 1` or that +1 should work, because 4 < 10.  The table always takes at least 3 entries to gain another digit.  I haven't investigated this.  (And have already spent longer than I meant to on this. :P)

**Or right-shift a lot more to just get a starting point for the loop.**  e.g. `mult = clz(ls) >= 18 ? 100000 : 10;`, or a 3 or 4-way chain of `if`.

---

Or loop on `mult *= 100`, and after exiting that loop sort out whether you want `old_mult * 10` or `mult`.  (i.e. check if you went too far).  This cuts the iteration count in half for even numbers of digits.

(**Watch out for a possible infinite loop on large `ls` that would overflow the result.**  If `mult *= 100` wraps to 0, it will always stay `<= ls` for `ls = 1000000000`, for example.)