# How to concatenate 2 numbers using bit-wise operator, leaving initial values of variables intact?

Tags: c, bit-shift

> I can not use sprintf, or any other function that puts everything together in a string n, I can not really use any libc function, it's part of a challenge I'm trying to solve

Given:

```
int x=5;
int y=2;
```

Expected Output:

```
res = 52;
```

Comment: Do you want `y=52` leaving `x=5`?

Comment: I want x = 52, or another variable that has the concatenation of 2, without using any libc function

Comment: Well this would print 52 leaving initial values of x, y intact `int result = (x<<3)+(x<<1)+y;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was thinking of doing bitwise myself, it helped me a lot, hehe, for higher values than 9, the result would not compensate to do this, but I'll get value from 1 to 9 even then, vlw, :) @Krishna

Comment: I just found a similar answer which way more faster
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700533/8963175

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one posible solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int x= 342;
   int y= 224;
   int aux = y;
   while( aux ) {
      aux /= 10;
      x*= 10;
   }
   x+= y;
   printf("x= %d\r\n", x);  // prints 342224
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I tested here and with some values it really works, however if x is less than 10, it will do the sum

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that edge case!  Glad it was helpful  XD

Comment: Shouldn't it be `aux = y`?

Comment: Thank you, I did not even pay attention, thank you both

Comment: People, now I need to get all the numbers of the array, for example: char * array = "12345", I want to have int x = 12345, again without using the libc functions, I tried to adapt from the examples that passed me to solve, but without success , thankful.

Comment: The solution referred to by @Abhishek is much better, avoiding a division in the loop