# Flutter/Dart: Concatenat integers

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to concatenate integers without converting to String first?

```
int _test1 = 123;
int _test2 = 456;

print(int.parse(("$_test1"+"$_test2"))); // 123456
```

Comment: what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink To join _test1 and _test2 into one number (123456), but keeping it an integer. Wasn't sure if there is a better way to the one I illustrated

Comment: `_test1 * 1000 + _test2`

Comment: @pskink That assumes the integers are the same length though

Comment: no, you can have `_test1` as any number

Comment: @pskink But not _test2

Comment: My bad I didn't read without converting to String first.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it like this

```
void main() {
    int _test1 = 123;
    int _test2 = 456;
    int pow = 10;
    while(_test2 >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
  print(_test1 *pow + _test2);
}
```

source : [How to concatenate two integers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700497/how-to-concatenate-two-integers-in-c)