# Put two different variable integers into another variable

Tags: java

I have to numbers saved into variables.

```
int a = 1; int b = 1;
```

and then I want to put these numbers together in another variable like:

```
int c=ab; // so the value here would be then 11.
```

Comment: LOL that can't be done unless you are storing them as string

Comment: `int c = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b));`

Comment: How to you want to combine the two numbers?  There is no standard way of doing this, it is up to you.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I didn't know that that is not possible, I will convert then them to Strings. Thank you!

Comment: Next time when you post something, please share what have you done so far, instead of asking for the solution.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140721/concatenating-two-int-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int c = (int) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(b))+1)*a + b.
```

Complete program

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 1234;
        int b = 567890;
        int c = (int) Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(b))+1)*a + b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Test

```
1234567890
```

You can try it [online](http://ideone.com/HM3D8E).

Comment: At least one answerer who doesn't use the lame version. :)

Comment: @Tom Some guys got it, some guys don't

Comment: This one is a clever one, I like it.

Answer (score 5):

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;

String ab = "" + a + b;
int c = Integer.parseInt(ab);
```

Answer (score 5):

Convert to `String`, concatenate, then parse back to `Integer`.

```
int a = 1, b = 1;

int c = Integer.parseInt( "" + a + b );
```

Answer (score 2):

Like `String` concatenation?

```
int c = Integer.parseInt("" + a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String stringA = String.valueOf(a);
String stringB = String.valueOf(b);
String stringC = stringA + stringB;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, atleast in Java.

But it is not impossible. Here is a weird way

```
int c=Integer.parseInt(a+""+b);
```

Ofcourse you get better ideas if you could tell us what is your ultimate aim.